# Can't change alpha of subview when cell is focused

Tags: swift, focus, tvos

I have a simple imageView added to a custom UICollectionViewCell. I initialize it when i declare it:

```
let likeIcon = UIImageView()
```

And then I set properties in my class' initializer:

```
  likeIcon.image = UIImage(named: "heart_empty")!
  likeIcon.alpha = 0.0
  addSubview(likeIcon)
```

Nothing too crazy. I want the imageView to be hidden initially but then visible when the cell is clicked.

I have a simple method that I call when the cell is selected (it's not animated yet):

```
func toggleLikeButtonAnimated() {

    likeIcon.frame = likeIconFrame()
    likeIcon.alpha = 1.0
}
```

But the icon doesn't show.

1. If I comment out the initial `likeIcon.alpha = 0.0` then the icon is visible selected or unselected, so it's there
2. `toggleLikeButtonAnimated` is definitely called
3. The frame is the correct frame

The only thing I can think of, since this is really strange, is that something with the focus engine is interfering with the alpha changing.

I have this code in the cell right now:

```
 // MARK: -- Focus
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)

    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
        if self.focused {
            self.focusItem()
        } else {
            self.unfocusItem()
        }
        }) { () -> Void in
    }
}

func focusItem() {

    self.overlay.alpha = 0.0
}


func unfocusItem() {

    self.overlay.alpha = 0.6
}
```

The `overlay` is below the icon so it shouldn't interfere with it's visibility. So I tried this:

```
// MARK: -- Focus
    override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)

        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            if self.focused {
                self.focusItem()
            } else {
                self.unfocusItem()
            }
            }) { () -> Void in
        }
    }

    func focusItem() {

        self.overlay.alpha = 0.0
        self.likeIcon.alpha = 1.0
    }


    func unfocusItem() {

        self.overlay.alpha = 0.6
        self.likeIcon.alpha = 0.0
    }
```

The `likeIcon` animates in when the cell is focused and out when unfocused. But this is not what I want, and it seems like the animation of the focus engine is preventing my alpha change when selected.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

According your description，you want the imageView to be hidden initially but then visible when the UICollectionViewCell is clicked, but it is did't work. When you set  UICollectionViewDelegate，you must be call `reloadData` function，just like UITableView.Maybe you can try use this when you click cell.Solve you problem yet.

Comment: I shouldn't have to reloadData to change the appearance of once cell. It seems like the focus API is interfering with updates on the UI of the cell.